# How to limit the user input in range?

Tags: python, list

2 inputs has to enter by the user. first number is How many elements you can enter?
Let's say 5, then user can only insert 5 elements

```
K = int(input())
L =[]
for i in range(K):
    L.append(i)
```

K =5
we need to enter 5 values like 11 22 33 44 55

Desired out put

L = [11,22,33,44,55]

Can we do something like

```
k=int(input())
L = list(input().split()) for _ in range(k)
```

so that I can give the digits in one shot

Comment: You need another `input()` inside the loop, and then you should append that value instead of `i`.

Comment: what is the second input from the user?

Comment: What do you think `L.append(i)` is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be specific and clear.I cant understand what you are trying to ask.Limiting the range in input? You aldready limit you input by fixing a range.

If i understood your question correctly then here is my solution:

```
k=int(input())
print([input() for i in range(k)])
```

This is the easiest way rather than appending.

If you need to give space seperated input then you can use split funtion

Answer (score 1):

All you're missing here is the second input that the for loop.

```
K = int(input())
L =[]
for i in range(K):
    L.append(input())
print(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
K = int(raw_input())
print K

finalList = []
for i in range(K):
    finalList.append(int(raw_input()))

print finalList
```

OUTPUT:
python test4.py
5
5
11
22
33
44
55
[11, 22, 33, 44, 55]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you're just missing one line. You ask for the user to specify `K`, which they do. You follow it with a loop that runs `K`-times. However, you forgot to have the user input these `K` values into `L`

Adding that extra line would look something like this:

```
for i in range(K):
    input_int = int( input() )
    L.append( input_int )
```